# How to show a survey form to users according to their role in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

I have created 3 form with the help of contact form7 and I'm using contact form DB to store the details filled by the user to the database. How would it be possible to show that forms according to the user roles and user can fill that form only once! If a particular user already filled that form he won't see that form ever. And while the user is filling the form all the features on the screen will be disabled.

Comment: How important is it that a user doesn't fill the form in twice? Put another way, how secure are you aiming to be? What do you mean by "all the features on the screen will be disabled?" What research have you done so far and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to do this with two conditions

First:
If user is .... 
Source: (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata)

Second: I would add a hidden field with a default value or just a simple counter.
If counter is ...